# How to convert pdf to doc/docx and vice versa in python

Tags: python, pdf-conversion

I want to convert *doc/docx* file into *pdf* , make some changes in file and convert *pdf* back to *doc/docx* using python.
To convert to *pdf* `docx2pdf` can be used but *pdf* cant be saved to file. I need to read keep converted file in memory, not sure how to read the converted *pdf* into `fitz` module. (same for *pdf* to *docx* , `pdf2docx` module is used to convert *pdf* file into *docx* but how to read converted *docx* to stream ?

docx to pdf :

```py
from docx2pdf import convert
convert("input.docx")
convert("input.docx", "output.pdf")
```

pdf to docx:

```py
from pdf2docx import parse
pdf_file = "test.pdf"
word_file = "test.docx"
parse(pdf_file, word_file, start=0, end=None)
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert docx to pdf, do some changes on the pdf and convert the pdf back to docx ? Can't you just use a docx parser and do the changes in the docx itself ?

Comment: @John Doe, i  have code ready for pdf files changes, these changes will be same for all doc/docx file also,so i just want to convert doc/docx file to pdf n call the code for changes and convert back to doc/docx format again.

Comment: @KJ , ok ,  how can we read the docx/pdf file into stream using above code , any idea please

Comment: @KJ ,ok, thanks for the reply, will try n test